# How to change this CSS code to get required layout

Tags: css

The following is my CSS code. With this code I am getting 100px width left and right menus, and 700px width middle content. (A total width of 900px.) However, my requirement is 100px width left and right sidebars and 800 px width middle content. (Total width 1000px.) How should change the following CSS code to do that? I tried my best, but it messes up when changing values.

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 100px;
    background: url("assets/bg_paper.jpg") repeat-x;
}
body {
    font: 76% arial,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
p { margin: 0 10px 10px }
a {
    display: block;
    color: #981793;
    padding: 10px;
}
div#header h1 {
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #79B30B;
}
div#container { text-align: left }
div#content p { line-height: 1.4 }
div#navigation { background: #ffffff }
div#extra { background: #FFffff }
div#footer {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #FFF;
}
div#footer p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
div#container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div#wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
div#content { margin: 0 100px }
div#navigation {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -900px;
}
div#extra {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: -100px;
}
div#footer {
    clear: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

---

```
<!---- language:HTML-------->
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header"><h1>Header</h1></div>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
<p><strong>1) Content here.</strong> column long long column very long fill fill fill long text text column text silly very make long very fill silly make make long make text fill very long text column silly silly very column long very column filler fill long make filler long silly very long silly silly silly long filler make column filler make silly long long fill very.</p>
<p>very make make fill silly long long filler column long make silly silly column filler fill fill very filler text fill filler column make fill make text very make make very fill fill long make very filler column very long very filler silly very make filler silly make make column column </p>
<p>fill long make long text very make long fill column make text very silly column filler silly text fill text filler filler filler make make make make text filler fill column filler make silly make text text fill make very filler column very </p>
<p>column text long column make silly long text filler silly very very very long filler fill very fill silly very make make filler text filler text make silly text text long fill fill make text fill long text very silly long long filler filler fill silly long make column make silly long column long make very </p>
</div>
</div>
<div id="navigation">
<p><strong>2) Navigation here.</strong> long long fill filler very fill column column silly filler very filler fill fill filler text fill very silly fill text filler silly silly filler fill very make fill column text column very very column fill fill very silly column silly silly fill fill long filler </p>
</div>
<div id="extra">
<p><strong>3) More stuff here.</strong> column long make silly silly filler silly very very very long column filler fill make column make silly column fill silly column long make silly filler column filler silly long long column fill silly column very </p>
</div>
<div id="footer"><p>Here it goes the footer</p></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: HTML?.. check out jsfiddle(jsfiddle.net) - you can replicate your problem.

Comment: Indeed difficult to assist without corresponding HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
div#container {
width: 1000px;
margin: 0 auto;}
```

Hope this will helps!! or reply me back..

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the HTML code too for this problem. May be you have not properly placed the contents on your page. So, it would be easy to tell if you post the HTML file here too.